# How can my Windows application handle a subdomain or path URI?

Tags: winapi, registry

My Windows desktop application handles a specific URI scheme, let's call it `myscheme:`, so URLs like `myscheme://what/ever` open my app. We set that up by creating a registry key and several values under `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\myscheme`. (It's an app that installs per-user without requiring elevation, thus the use of `HKEY_CURRENT_USER`.)

I would also like to be able to handle `http:` and `https:` URLs in a specified subdomain or path, such as `http://mysubdomain.example.com/what/ever`. Android provides a way to do this; can I do it in Windows?

I don't need a working example (I'm a fairly experienced Windows developer). All I'm looking for, if the capability exists, is a pointer to any relevant registry key or API name/docs on MSDN or elsewhere - I can take it from there. Thanks!

Comment: [_URL monikers allow an application to bind a resource, specified by a URL, to a moniker._](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms775150(v=vs.85).aspx) ... but this will propably only work if Internet Explorer is the default browser as the API is listed under "Internet Explorer Platform APIs".